# Can we Host a ASP.NET Core 2.2 MVC project on IIS without publish it?

Tags: iis, asp.net-core, iis-7, asp.net-core-mvc

Can we Host a  ASP.NET Core 2.2 MVC project on IIS  without publish it ?

Comment: Nope. It is not designed that way. Many important pieces (like `web.config`) are only generated during the publish process. Why cannot you do `dotnet publish`? It is just a simple command.

Answer (score 0):

Try to right-click your project, choose Properities->Debug->Launch, choose `IIS` for launching. That will host project on IIS. You need to run as adminstrator permission and install [Development time IIS support](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2017/07/13/development-time-iis-support-for-asp-net-core-applications/) for vs.